# How to convert a jquery array to a string array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran the following jquery command:

```
x=$(".container h3")
```

and got back this response:

```
[<h3>​A</h3>​, <h3>​B​</h3>​, <h3>​C​</h3>​, <h3>​D​</h3>​, <h3>​E</h3>​]
```

I would like to convert each of the elements in the array to a string, so the final result would look like this:

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

The problem is that I can't convert each jquery response object into a string element.

I tried to cast each object as a String, via:

```
for(var i=0; i < x.length; ++i) {console.log( String(x[i]) )}
```

But I got back this:

```
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
```

Is there a direct way of converting each object into a string element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method?

```
var x = $(".container h3").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get(); // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Comment: note: if IE support is not required, `return this.textContent` will do

Comment: note that iteration is not the problem. The stringification was.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = [];
$(".container h3").each(function(){
    x.push($(this).text());
});
```